# Don't know the name of the control I want (textBox+Scrollbar), on silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I'm learning Silverlight and I want a control that lets the user enter a number but also that has 2 buttons like a scrollbar and when one of the buttons is pushed the value decrements/increments accordingly.
Sorry I guess it should be pretty easy, the book I have is pretty basic (I'll get another one when I get a chance)

Like this:

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for an UpDown control, also called a spinbox.

You can find [one](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Control%20Overview%20Pg3) in the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/).